# How to do form authentication by entering username and password while web crawler is crawling pages

Tags: java, file-io, web-crawler, websphinx

I have downloaded websphinx to do this but i need it to ask me username and password of website and then submit the username and password to the website and once authenticated it should start crawling the internal links and sublinks and save the static data of end page into excel file.Is there any other method or crawler to do this but in java only

Comment: saum22, what kind of authorization it is? Apache auth, website custom aut, something else?

Comment: There is dis website in internet which i need to crawl but at home page only its is asking for username and password.How should i do this ,so that user of crwaler enters username and password,and crawler submits the field entered to the website form,once authenticated,it should start crwaling inside pages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with websphinx but could you set the url to include the username and password for basic authentication:

https://username:password@myserver.mydomain.com/